# Including dagger generated sources in an apklib

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin, dagger

I have a mavenized apklib which uses dagger (1.1.0) internally. The maven build generates the `annotations` folder inside the build output folder with the appropriate adapter classes. However, these are not included in the generated apklib.

What's the correct configuration for the build process to include the generated sources inside the apklib?

I'm using maven v3.0.4, android-maven-plugin v3.6.0 and the maven-compiler-plugin v3.1

**Edit: Here's my `pom.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyMMdddHHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <android.version>4.3</android.version>
        <versionCode>${maven.build.timestamp}</versionCode>
        <android.sdk.platform>18</android.sdk.platform>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Other dependencies... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
                        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: We may be interested in seeing your POM file.

Answer (score 1):

Just use maven-resources-plugin to copy the generated source where you want. "directory" is the source directory, in your target/... 
you shoud modify the "phase" to a post source generation phase like "prepare-package".

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>copy-resources1</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/...</outputDirectory>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/...</directory><!-- source dir-->
          <include>**/*</include>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What outputDirectory do I specify to get the folder into the apklib?

Comment: I think your generated classes are in target/classes so then the outputdirectory is like:  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>